# Manual grub rescue exit when booting up

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Community!

Every time I restart my PC, I get in the `grub rescue>` prompt, just because before that I accidentally deleted a volume with my linux distro, including `grub`(my PC is dual-bootable). Using some external tools, I restored the partition, and its number changed from `6 to 4`.

The problem is that every time I boot my PC, I need manually run such commands as

```
set prefix=(hd0,4)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,4)
```

because as I said, previous number of partition was `4` instead of `6`, and PC do not save this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update grub configuration.

On Ubuntu or similar: `update-grub`

On Fedora or similar: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: After updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, the problem disappeared by itself.

Comment: For when you upgrade the grub package, the update-grub script is run in the process.